# Spark: Convert a Dataset<Row> to key and value to be added in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying Spark connected to a Kafka topic which has Location Data.
I want to convert the df (the dataframe result) to key value pairs so that i can output it to another Kafka topic

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream().format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
            .option("subscribe", "cab-location")
            .option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load();
    df = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
    .map(new MapFunction<Row, Tuple2<String,String>>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, String> call(Row value) throws Exception {
            Gson g = new Gson();  
            CabLocationData cabLocationData = g.fromJson(value.getString(1), CabLocationData.class);
            return new Tuple2<String, String>(value.getString(0), cabLocationData.getCabName());
        }
    }, Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.STRING()))
    .map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<String,String>, Row>(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Row call(Tuple2<String, String> value) throws Exception {
            return RowFactory.create(value._1.toString(), value._2);
        }
    }, Encoders.javaSerialization(Row.class));
```

When I check df.columns() it shows only 1 column which is value.

Could you help to convert the Dataset to have 2 columns 1 for key and 1 for value so I can push it as key value pair to another Kafka topic

Comment: Note: SparkSQL has a built-in JSON parser; you shouldn't use Gson, let alone construct a new instance of that for every one Kafka record

Comment: Okay got it, but is there a way when we map a Dataset<Row> we can specify the column names also. Currently when I map the dataset, it is getting created with only one column which is value.

Comment: As mentioned, you shouldn't use Row objects at all. `withColumn` function in SparkSQL can define columns, yes, or you can use something like `selectExpr("get_json_object(value, '$.cabName') AS cab_name")`. See pyspark example with creating custom columns - https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb

Comment: Thank you .withColumn suggestion worked. Also I didnt' have convert Dataset<Tuple2<String,String>> to Dataset<Row>

Comment: Feel free to show your working solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @OneCricketeer with the suggestion.
Below is the code which worked

As discussed added the .withColumn to add column key and value from tuple columns _1 and _2

```
  Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream().format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "cab-location")
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load();
        Dataset<Tuple2<String, String>> df2 = df
        .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
        .map(new MapFunction<Row, Tuple2<String,String>>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, String> call(Row value) throws Exception {
                Gson g = new Gson();  
                CabLocationData cabLocationData = g.fromJson(value.getString(1), CabLocationData.class);
                return new Tuple2<String, String>(value.getString(0), cabLocationData.getCabName());
            }
        }, Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.STRING()));
        
        df2
        .withColumn("key", df2.col("_1"))
        .withColumn("value", df2.col("_2"))
        .writeStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
        .option("checkpointLocation", "C:\\Workspace\\Java\\app\\ch")
        .option("topic", "location-output")
        .outputMode("append").start().awaitTermination();
```